# Unknown growth on window

Tags: mold, removal, moss

I found this growth on several of my back windows.

[image: Growth]

I'm not sure if it is mold or moss or something else entirely.  Hoping someone could help me identify it and how to safely remove it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like moss growing in the window putty, probably from accumulated dust/dirt. Don’t think it’s dangerous but you’d need to remove the screen first and then scrape it off using something non-abrasive and blunt as you don’t want to damage the putty underneath (or the glass). A plastic paint scraper would probably do the trick.